# Calling forceUpdate inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, jsx

I'm not good with `this` notation, so I have some troubles when try to call method forceUpdate() inside my jsx.

```
class WeatherList extends Component {
renderWeather(cityData){


    //some code


    return(
        <tr key={id}>
            <td>
                <div>{name}</div>
                <h4 onClick={ () => {
                    var toChange = JSON.parse(localStorage.nameForData);
                    for(var i in toChange){
                        if(toChange[i].city.id = id){
                            toChange.splice(i,1);
                        }
                    }
                    localStorage.nameForData = JSON.stringify(toChange);
                    forceUpdate();

                }} >Delete</h4>
            </td>
            <td><Chart data={temps} color='orange' units='K' /></td>
            <td><Chart data={pressures} color='blue' units='hPa' /></td>
            <td><Chart data={humidities} color='green' units='%' /></td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

I tried to bind `forceUpdate` to `this` in constructor, but I'm getting error message `Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined` again and again.

**Full code**

```
class WeatherList extends Component {   

renderWeather(cityData){
    const name = cityData.city.name;
    const temps = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);
    const pressures = cityData.list.map(weather=>weather.main.pressure);
    const humidities = cityData.list.map(weather=>weather.main.humidity);
    const id = cityData.city.id;



    return(
        <tr key={id}>
            <td>
                <div>{name}</div>
                <h4 onClick={ () => {
                    var toChange = JSON.parse(localStorage.nameForData);
                    for(var i in toChange){
                        if(toChange[i].city.id = id){
                            toChange.splice(i,1);
                        }
                    }
                    localStorage.nameForData = JSON.stringify(toChange);
                    forceUpdate();

                }} >Delete</h4>
            </td>
            <td><Chart data={temps} color='orange' units='K' /></td>
            <td><Chart data={pressures} color='blue' units='hPa' /></td>
            <td><Chart data={humidities} color='green' units='%' /></td>
        </tr>
    );
}


render(){

    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameForData'));

    arr = arr.concat(this.props.weather);

    localStorage.setItem('nameForData', JSON.stringify(arr));

    //localStorage.setItem('nameForData', JSON.stringify(this.props.weather));
    console.log(arr);

    return(
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Temperature (K)</th>
                    <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
                    <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {arr.map(this.renderWeather)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Pls, provide full `WeatherList` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't bind `forceUpdate` function. Use it by calling `this.forceUpdate()`.

Correct code:

```
// `renderWeather` function:

<h4 onClick={ () => {
    var toChange = JSON.parse(localStorage.nameForData);
    for(var i in toChange){
        if(toChange[i].city.id = id){
            toChange.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    localStorage.nameForData = JSON.stringify(toChange);
    this.forceUpdate();

}} >Delete</h4>
```

As you are passing `this.renderWeather` function to `map`, it `this` context would be `undefined`, to set correct `this` context, you should pass it as second argument to `map` function:

```
// `render` function:

<tbody>
  {arr.map(this.renderWeather, this)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried this also, but still get that error about undefined.

Comment: @K.Rice, you should remove binding `forceUpdate` from constructor.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined

Comment: @K.Rice, see updated question. You should provide `this` context to `map` function